# Increase or decrease volume in blackberry programmatically

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my application I play a video on device and when I tap on screen while video is playing a popup window is opened at the center of the screen with a volume button on that popup screen. When I click on that button volume should increase and after maximum level of volume it should decrease. I don't know how to do it programmatically in BlackBerry.

Comment: I'd recommend going to the Blackberry Developer's site, and searching the documentation for "volume"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Check the article on video playing, [Play a video in a UI field in a
>
>   BlackBerry device application](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Create_BB_app_that_plays_a_video_in_a_UI_field_739692_11.jsp), on *section 8*, the article
>   describes how to control volume.

To control the volume, you need to get `javax.microedition.media.control.VolumeControl` object from the `javax.microedition.media.Player` object.

Invoking `Player.getControl()`, using a String parameter with the name of the control will return the control object. Example code:

```
private VolumeControl getVolumeControl(Player player) 
{
    return (VolumeControl) player.getControl("VolumeControl");
}
```

After you have the `VolumeControl` object you can use `int setLevel(int level)` to set the volume level. API Link [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/control/VolumeControl.html#setLevel%28int%29).

You can check the Video Support section of the [BlackBerry Java Application - Fundamental Guilds](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/9091/JDE_5.0_FundamentalsGuide_Beta.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for reply.can u send me a full source code.

Comment: I don't have access to source code right now, but you can check the article (added on top of the answer).

Comment: HI Actually i want to increase or decrease volume on single button click.WHEN I click on button volume increase upto maximum(100). after maximum level when i click on same button volume should be decrease but its no working.

Comment: Post your code, and try to modify / improve your logic for controlling volume level.